# Can I manually add a jar file to android private library?

Tags: android

I want to include the guava-07.jar in my project.I tried configuring build paths,copying it to library folder,linking source and used add external jars.

The import com.google.common.eventbus.Subscribe cannot be resolved keeps showing.
I have a project with guava.jar in its private library.Can I put that in this project.Or is there another problem.Please help me understand.

Comment: first remove all the dependencies from jar file. After that right click --> Build path --> add to build path. Clean the project after it as well.

Comment: yes the same error keeps coming

Comment: no I did not get it solved.Tried a different library instead.

Comment: did it solved your problem? which library you used?

Comment: Actually I was using a custom library that used guava.When I was trying to use that in my project guava did not integrate properly.I simply deleted the entire project and imported from backup.This time the private library was already there with guava in it!I tried the same custom library it worked by just building the path.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse, just copy `guava-07.jar` into `libs` folder(create one if you don't have it).

Answer (score 0):

Select the files in windows explorer and drag them to the libs folder in eclipse.  This will also add them to the Android Private Libraries.